# Search in wikidata with specific Q code

Tags: wikidata, wikipedia, sparql

I've this query but I can't understand why doesn't return any result. I try different versions (with link, with only code, with wd:code) but nothing seems to work. What I need is this query but searching by code (like the eg., Q6015113)

```
              SELECT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {

 ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  FILTER (?item = "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q6015113")
 SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "es,en,fr" . }
} ORDER BY ASC(?num)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, URIs are "things, not strings". The filtering condition should be:

- `?item = <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q6015113>`, or
- `?item = wd:Q6015113`, or
- `?item = URI("http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q6015113")`.

There also exists the [`VALUES`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data) keyword for providing inline data.

Comment: mmm actually i don't wanna try to search for url, but for id (Q6015113). Tried with your example is not a valid query :(

Comment: sorry, it works now.   FILTER (?item = wd:Q6015113)

Comment: The only solution that works, although it is **quite slow**, is [the one with `?item = URI("http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q6015113")`](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5.%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Fitem%20%3D%20URI%28%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2FQ6015113%22%29%29%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22es%2Cen%2Cfr%22%20.%20%7D%0A%7D%20%0AORDER%20BY%20ASC%28%3Fnum%29). The first two solutions return nothing for me. See next comments.

Comment: First solution **not** working: [with `?item = <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q6015113>`](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5.%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Fitem%20%3D%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2FQ6015113%3E%29%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22es%2Cen%2Cfr%22%20.%20%7D%0A%7D%20%0AORDER%20BY%20ASC%28%3Fnum%29)

Comment: Second solution **not** working: [with `?item = wd:Q6015113`](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5.%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Fitem%20%3D%20wd%3AQ6015113%29%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22es%2Cen%2Cfr%22%20.%20%7D%0A%7D%20%0AORDER%20BY%20ASC%28%3Fnum%29)